# Menu Item Click in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am very new in android development (eclipse).i am try to do the following things.
1. generate a menu list when click on menu button in the eclipse
2. when clicking on the menu item navigate another page(xml page). i use the following codes.

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="About"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="Help" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.menuoptions;

import com.example.menuoptions.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.help:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

About.java

```
 package com.example.menuoptions;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 public class About extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

   }
  }
```

about.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About Page" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is in my second need. The menu items are listed but when clicking on the about item it is not navigate to about.xml.

Comment: Getting any error ?? if so can you post your logcat?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: @Beginner: no nothing happend. stay in main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.about:
startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
return true;
case R.id.help:
startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: i din't notice  this `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. sorry my mistake

Comment: @Parvathiiiii what did it throws and at where...??

Comment: @PiyushGupta i din't notice the change. so i deleted my previous comment. its not your fault

Answer (score 0):

have you provided the permission in manifest file?

```
 <activity android:name=".About" />
```

Comment: this is not a permission its an entry for the activity in manifest

Comment: @Anil: there is no change in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

simple code for menu selected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Try to use this

Comment: What is the R.id.new_game: case??/