# Handle clicks on menu item in toolbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

How to handle clicks from a toolbar with Navigation Component in android?
I have a `MaterialToolbar` in an activity with a menu in xml, the menu shows up and accepts clicks but no action is executed.
This is how I initialize the navigation component:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home);
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container);
appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
    .setDrawerLayout(binding.activityHome)
    .build();
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navigationView, navController);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolBar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

This is my Toolbar `menu`, it has only one item that will open a `DialogFragment`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dialog_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_account"
        android:title="@string/dialog_account"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then this is the `dialog` in the `navigation_graph`

```
   <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialog_account"
        android:name="my.package.name.dialogs.DialogAccount"
        android:label="@string/dialog_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog_account" />
```

This is the activity layout, nothing fancy there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="end">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_container"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                    style="@style/toolbar_style"
                    app:menu="@menu/toolbar" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/null_dimen"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            style="@style/navigation_view" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

The Activity layout has a `NavigationView` and a `MaterialToolbar`, the navigation from the `NavigationView` works fine, but I can't find a way to open my dialog from the `Toolbar` even though it seems like is taking clicks but doing nothing. I have tried with `onCreateOptionsMenu` but it does not get triggered, guess the Navigation Component is working but my dialog is not opening on touching of the menu.

What am I missing here, any hand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682102/how-to-navigate-to-a-fragment-on-menu-item-click-using-android-jetpack-navigatio/60682870#60682870

Comment: @MohammedAlaa None of the overridable Menu related options are triggered upon click, I guess is because `navigation-component` has taken control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Menu Item Click in android eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910216/menu-item-click-in-android-eclipse)

Comment: @tohidnoori I'm looking to make it work with `navigation-component`.

Comment: @Racu did you tried the sample in the mentioned question, the key is to use 
`override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }`

Comment: I have tried that one already before posting the question, had 2 issues, first, `onOptionsItemSelected` never triggered, second I couldn't make autocompletion to get me `onNavDestinationSelected`, maybe I'm missing something somewhere else, but can't find it.

Comment: Just tried again pushing `onOptionsItemSelected` but does not recognize the method.

Comment: I think that's because navigation library version you are using in dependanceis

Comment: I just checked again the link you shared and I can see that you are using `2.3.0-alpha`
I'll try that one.

Comment: @MohammedAlaa, no, did not work neither, I must be missing something.

Comment: what did you got, you can edit your question with that or move to chat if you want

Comment: `item` does not have any method `navigation` related. Upgraded to `2.3.0-beta01`, but I have not tried without setting the `clickListener` as @Deepanshu suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214802/discussion-between-mohammed-alaa-and-racu).

Answer (score 2):

To handle on click on Toolbar simply use "setOnMenuItemClickListener" by providing id of the toolbar.

```
  mToolbar= findViewById(R.id.main_tollbar);
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.game_menu);
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.search_menu:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Search Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.menus_logout:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Logout Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.acc_settings:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Setting Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.about_menu:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"About Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.feedback_menu:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Feedback Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That works, but is the right way to do it with `navigation-component`?

Comment: Ya Both are correct ya you are right Navigation-component is preferred most

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Toolbar` (without using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`) you have to use:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar,navController,mAppBarConfiguration);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(context, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
           return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
       }
});
```

In your case it is enough since the `id` in the menu matches with the `id` in the navigation graph. 
In general you can also use:

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
      Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action...);
      //....
}
```

Final note: the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` is only triggered if your are using an `ActionBar`.

Comment: That's my setup at the moment, added the `OnMenuItemClickListener` because of the asnwer of @Deepanshu 
Thought there that `NavigationUI` would handle the action, the `Item` is clearly taking cliks without the `OnMenuItemClickListener` but doing nothing.

In the mean time I'm just doing what you suggest.

Comment: @Racu can you debug and check if the `onMenuItemClick` os triggered and what is the result of `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);`?

Comment: Everything is working as expected with the `OnMenuItemClickListener`, I did that more than a week ago, you can see my comment in @Deepanshu answer. The issue is that I thought that `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar,navController,mAppBarConfiguration);` was enough to execute the action as it is for `NavigationDrawer`

Answer (score 0):

For Navigation component you can use inflator

```
val view-inflater.inflate(R.Layout.fragment_main, container, false)

view.textview1.setonClickListener{


Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.settings)
}
```